# How do I properly validate a field from the Transaction when the Hold field is unchecked on the Document?

Tags: acumatica

I have a Document/Transaction (FormGrid) structure to a custom screen.  I need to validate the values in the Transaction level when the Hold box is unchecked in the header.  Fundamentally, my challenge seems to come from order of operation for event handlers.  (FieldVerifying -> FieldUpdating -> Field Updated -> RowUpdating -> RowUpdated) combined with order of views processed (Seems to be the primary view before the others).

What has me completely confused right now is that if I leave the field in the transaction (grid) section of my form, CommitChanges fires, and everything is ok.  However, if I set my field (OrderQty) to 0 and then immediately go uncheck Hold in the header without "leaving" the OrderQty field first, the OrderQty value is not committed until AFTER the Hold checkbox is processed.  That means that I cannot validate that OrderQty is greater than 0.  Literally, I cannot see my OrderQty value in the Cache or any form of the view because the hold box in the header is being processed before the OrderQty in the grid.

I have tried simple means to do the tests, and this is a snippit of something a bit more complex to try to grab the data.  Caches[].Updated holds the new values AFTER the hold checkbox is processed, not before.  AddWithoutDuplicates is a method to simply make sure I didn't have the record in the list already (allows looking at the updated cache values rather than the old values not yet committed)

```
        List<SSRQLine> list = new List<SSRQLine>();

        foreach (SSRQLine line in Caches[typeof(SSRQLine)].Updated)
        {
            AddWithoutDuplicates(list, line);
        }

        foreach (SSRQLine line in Caches[typeof(SSRQLine)].Inserted)
        {
            AddWithoutDuplicates(list, line);
        }

        foreach (SSRQLine line in Lines.Select())
        {
            AddWithoutDuplicates(list, line);
        }

        foreach (SSRQLine line in list)
        ...
```

Is there  way to validate the grid data from the hold checkbox reliably during entry?   Or must I handle the validation in a RowPersisting event later?  Or any other suggestions on how to validate the user entry in the grid from Hold_FieldVerifying?

Comment: do you have commit changes on the qty field? also the order of fields fired is usually the order of the placement in the DAC. (Hold listed before Qty in the DAC) Try swapping the placement which sometimes helps.

Comment: I do, which is why it surprises me that I must actually leave the field before checking the hold box.  If I am in the quantity field and click the hold box, commit changes does not fire from the field.  Also, they are not in the same DAC.  I think that's the complication that I don't quite understand well enough.  The screen is a FormGrid.  The hold field is in the Form (think SOOrder) and the quantity field is in the grid (think SOLine).  My aim was to complete a final validation of the lines on the request when taking the entire request off hold.

Comment: Originally, I did not validate the field itself because I wanted the user to be able to build the request without a quantity included.  However, the quantity must be greater than 0 to take it off of hold and initiate an approval process.  This allows requests to be created as templates for commonly needed items, like how an oil change on a car always needs oil and a filter, but not always a fresh set of rags.  By raising a WARNING instead of error on validating the field, the user can save the line.  Taking off hold and validating again on RowPersisting allows throwing an exception to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

The parent DAC is SSRQRequisition, and the child DAC is SSRQLine.

As the goal was to monitor taking the request off of hold, the original effort was attached to the header DAC's hold field.  The problem is that it required validating child DAC values in a One to Many relationship in which the child DAC had not processed its Field Events.  To warn the user but not prevent saving the request, create the following event handler:

```
#region SSRQLine_OrderQty_FieldVerifying
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldVerifying<SSRQLine.orderQty> e)
{
    SSRQLine row = (SSRQLine) e.Row;
    if((decimal?)e.NewValue == 0)
    {
        e.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SSRQLine.orderQty>(e.Row, row.OrderQty, new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.InvalidQuantity, PXErrorLevel.Warning));
    }
}
#endregion
```

To re-validate the entire request before allowing the user to save it upon taking the request off of hold, perform the validation in the header DAC's RowPersisting event handler.  Note that validation should not be performed if the request is being deleted, so the operation is tested as well.  Additionally, the test is only needed if the user is taking the request off of hold, so no need to validate when placing back on hold.

```
#region SSRQRequisition_RowPersisting
protected void _(Events.RowPersisting<SSRQRequisition> e)
{
    SSRQRequisition row = e.Row;
    if (e.Operation != PXDBOperation.Delete && row?.Hold == false)
    {
        ValidateConsignment();
    }
}
#endregion
```

The ValidateConsignment method has been created to simplify reading the code, but is called by the SSRQRequisition RowPersisting event.  By raising exception handling as an ERROR this time and throwing an exception, the user is alerted that the warning is now what prevents saving the record without it being on hold.

```
#region ValidateConsignment
protected virtual void ValidateConsignment()
{

    int lineCounter = 0;

    SSRQRequisition req = Requisitions.Current;

    List<SSRQLine> list = new List<SSRQLine>();

    foreach (SSRQLine line in Caches[typeof(SSRQLine)].Updated)
    {
        AddWithoutDuplicates(list, line);
    }

    foreach (SSRQLine line in Caches[typeof(SSRQLine)].Inserted)
    {
        AddWithoutDuplicates(list, line);
    }

    foreach (SSRQLine line in Lines.Select())
    {
        AddWithoutDuplicates(list, line);
    }

    foreach (SSRQLine line in list)
    {
        lineCounter++;

        if (line.SiteID == null)
        {
            throw new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.NoWhse, PXErrorLevel.Error);
        }

        if (line.OrderQty == null || line.OrderQty == 0)
        {
            this.Lines.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SSRQLine.orderQty>(line, line.OrderQty, new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.InvalidQuantity, PXErrorLevel.Error));
            throw new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.InvalidQuantity, PXErrorLevel.Error);
        }

    }
    if (lineCounter == 0)
    {
        this.Lines.Cache.RaiseExceptionHandling<SSRQRequisition.hold>(req, req.Hold, new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.NoLines, PXErrorLevel.Error));
        throw new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.NoLines, PXErrorLevel.Error);
    }

}
#endregion
```

The ValidateConsignment method currently cycles through the Inserted and Updated copies of the cache, but I may be able to remove these since it is no longer being tested before the updates are applied to the cache.  As this is now called from the RowPersisting method, all field and row event handlers for inserting and updating records in the cache should be applied already.  However, I'll be testing further before removing them.  Initial testing confirms that the code provided achieves the goal.  To provide the desired end user experience, the code simply needed to be spread across 3 different events rather than cramming it all into the event on the Hold checkbox that originally intended to initiate the checks.  The behavior ends up being slightly different than originally intended, but the result is more user friendly and achieves the same goal.